# What's wrong with my Angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Html is here:
    
        
            
            -->

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

        <title>Events Web</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="LoginController">
        <p>{{name}}, world</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My app.js is here:

```
var app = angular.module('LoginPage',[]);

app.controller('LoginController',['$scope',
    function($scope){
        $scope.name = "100";
}]);
```

Can some one please help me with this? I tried a lot and couldn't find any mistake.

May be its a small one, but I couldn't find what's the issue

Comment: Did you write `ng-app=LoginPage` in your HTML?
What is the issue you are facing? Any console errors in browser perhaps would be helpful.

Comment: There was no console errors. I added ng-app in <head> tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgot to add `ng-app="LoginPage"`

```
<html ng-app="LoginPage">
    <body ng-controller="LoginController">
         <p>{{name}}, world</p>
     </body>
</html>
```

See a basic example of Angularjs 1.3 setup - [Sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/yhbSRM5Ej8Lcuh6wCBUA)

Comment: Can't I add ng-app in <head> ?

Comment: If you add ng-app in head then inside head tag your controller will be avaliable, not out side the head tag.  body is outside of head tag.

Comment: No, because the `<head>` is not the container for controller.
See this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: ng-controller directive should be applied to a child element of ng-app directive.